# XML attribute finding

Tags: c#, xml

```xml
<Flight flightOriginDate="2018-08-20" scheduledTimeOfDeparture="2018-08-20T16:15:00">
    <FlightIdentification>
        <FLIGHTIDENTIFIGHER> ATS-FPL </FLIGHTIDENTIFIGHER> CLEAR
        <FlightNumber airlineIATACode="two letter code"  number="275"  operationalSuffix="A">
            <CommercialFlightNumber>275A</CommercialFlightNumber> --"concatnation of IATA Code, Number and operational Suffix"
        </FlightNumber>
    </FlightIdentification>
    <DepartureAirport AIRPORTNAME="PORTLAND INTL"  airportFunction="Departure Airport" -- HC MASTER >
        <AirportICAOCode>KPWM</AirportICAOCode>
        <AirportIATACode>PWM</AirportIATACode>
    </DepartureAirport>
    <ArrivalAirport airportName="HEATHROW"  airportFunction=" Arrival Airport"   >
        <AirportICAOCode>EGLL</AirportICAOCode>
        <AirportIATACode>LHR</AirportIATACode>
    </ArrivalAirport>
</Flight>
```

How to remove attribute which are in all letters capital letters in c# from an xml. For ex- FLIGHTIDENTIFIGHER, AIRPORTNAME in above xml

Comment: have you **tried anything** yourself so far? if so: please show us your effort. if not: try something yourself first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to add necessary namespaces:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;
```

Then you load your sample XML into XDocument.

```
var xDocument = XDocument.Load("XmlPath.xml");
```

And now with the help of LINQ, you delete elements and attributes which names are uppercase.

```
xDocument.Root.Descendants().Where(elem => elem.Name.LocalName.ToString()
                            .All(char.IsUpper))
                            .Remove();

xDocument.Root.Descendants().Attributes()
                            .Where(elem => elem.Name.ToString()
                            .All(char.IsUpper))
                            .Remove();
```

Comment: But one issue here. For a main root, if there are 2 child nodes and both of them got removed. Then the End tag is also missing for main root.

Comment: It is hard to understand when you don't have example. Could you share XML example that has problems with provided solution?

Comment: @ jaroslav_av can you please help me for my latest question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61237209/xml-parent-tag-removal-without-deleting-child-items-in-c-sharp