# XML Parent tag removal without deleting child items in c#

Tags: c#, xml

```
<Remarks remarksType="">
   <Remark>
     <Paragraph sequence="1">
       <Text />
     </Paragraph>
   </Remark>
</Remarks>
```

By using C# , In the above code i want to remove `<Remark>` and `</Remark>`. 
But it should not remove the child items.
Can anyone please help me.
I tried like this

```
XElement root = XElement.Parse(xml); // or .Parse(string)
var removes = root.XPathSelectElements("Remark");
foreach (XElement node in removes.ToArray())
{
node.AddBeforeSelf(node.Elements());
node.Remove();
}
root.Save(xml);
```

Thankyou

Comment: Do you get an error? Or just not the right results?

Comment: your code work well.have you tried it?

Comment: That code was not working. It was not going inside the foreach loop

Comment: I normally do it like this : foreach (XElement node in removes.ToArray())
{
    var newNodes = node.Elements();
    node.ReplaceWith(NewNodes);
}

Comment: @jdweng what is "removes"  inside the foreach loop?

Comment: The remove is not inside the for loop.  It is the array of items being enumerated.